# Change views but keep common top menu in Android SDK

Tags: android, menu, sdk, view

I want to have a common menu on top of all the views of my Android application. I know something about fragments but they are supported on versions > 3.0.
If this is true, what other options would I have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Fragments all the way down to Android 1.6 (API level 4) by using the Android support library.

Link: http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html

Comment: Actually support for Fragments is included in the v4 static support library. The 4 indicates API 4 which is Android v1.6

Comment: Actually, just for completeness - if the OP wants to use the Action Bar for the 'menu', that was added in the v7 static support library so will only work with Android v2.1 onwards.